# Communication to another process through pipes (as a pseudoterminal replacement) without blocking and without buffering in Windows, C/C++

Tags: c++, windows, pipe, pty

What I wanted to achieve is this:
An application (a "game" using SDL2 but that's not relevant to the problem) which can show multiple things on screen, one of those things can be a "computer terminal" that the user/player can interact with. But the in-game computer will be running a actual program on the real computer with its input and output redirected to the game. So basically the "game" will have to behave like a terminal to the "guest" program, like xterm or others like that. And I wanted this to work both on GNU/Linux and Windows.

So I started making a demo which does just this and nothing else.
Gets keyboard action and transforms it into text sent to the program, receives text from the program and draws it on screen.

On GNU/Linux I managed to do this.
Did this using a pseudoterminal which is a tool for exactly this purpose.
I create a pseudoterminal with openpty(), make it non-blocking, then I do a fork(), in the fork I redirect IO to the preudoterminal, set it as the controlling terminal and finally I do an execl() to run the guest program.
In the host program I regularly perform read() and write().
And this works fine.

Next is Windows.
Windows doesn't support the fork-exec so I do it the Windows way, with CreateProcess().
Windows also doesn't have pseudoterminals, so I use named pipes instead.
I know that pipes don't have all the capabilities of a pseudoterminal but for my needs that's ok.
So on Windows I create two pipes with CreateNamedPipe(), open the other sides with CreateFile(), with the handles inheritable, finally run the guest program with CreateProcess(), with the pipe handles set as the input and output.
In the host program I regularly perform ReadFile() and WriteFile().

This works too but not well.
Two unwanted things are happening.
First is that after the output (of guest program) pipe doesn't have any more bytes available the ReadFile() function would not return even though the pipes were created with the PIPE_NOWAIT flag.
But then I found out that the read was blocking only in Wine. In real Windows the read was non-blocking, like it should.
But there is a second thing.
The output (of guest program) pipe is being buffered by system.
When the guest program writes to its output (so to the pipe) the host program doesn't see any bytes to read. Only when the guest writes a big number of bytes then all of them go to the host all at once. And this is happening even though the pipe is opened on the guest end with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING.
This is not acceptable because I need real time interaction.

Below is the code which sets up the process and the pipes/pseudoterminal:

```
    bool LemlTerm::runCommand() {
#ifdef LEML_WIN32
    char ptyName[256];
    HANDLE ptyInM = NULL;
    HANDLE ptyInS = NULL;
    HANDLE ptyOutM = NULL;
    HANDLE ptyOutS = NULL;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sAtr;

    LPCSTR applName = "load.exe";
    LPSTR cmdLine = (LPSTR)"load.exe test";
    STARTUPINFO stInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION prInfo; 

    if (commandRunning)
        return false;

    fail=false;

    sAtr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
    sAtr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
    sAtr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

    snprintf(ptyName,256,"\\\\.\\pipe\\%08lx_LEML_PTY_IN",(unsigned long)GetCurrentProcessId());
    printf ("ptyIn: %s\n",ptyName);

    ptyInM = CreateNamedPipe (
        (LPCSTR) ptyName,
        PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND,
        PIPE_NOWAIT,
        1,
        TERMINAL_W,
        TERMINAL_W,
        0, //timeout
        NULL);

    if (ptyInM == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        fail=true;
        snprintf(errorText,256,"Could not open ptyM: %s.",ptyName);
        return false;
    }

    ptyInS = CreateFile (
        (LPCSTR) ptyName,
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        &sAtr,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
        NULL);

    if (ptyInS == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        fail=true;
        snprintf(errorText,256,"Could not open ptyS: %s.",ptyName);
        CloseHandle(ptyInM);
        return false;
    }

    snprintf(ptyName,256,"\\\\.\\pipe\\%08lx_LEML_PTY_OUT",(unsigned long)GetCurrentProcessId());
    printf ("ptyOut: %s\n",ptyName);

    ptyOutM = CreateNamedPipe (
        (LPCSTR) ptyName,
        PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND,
        PIPE_NOWAIT,
        1,
        TERMINAL_W,
        TERMINAL_W,
        0,  //timeout
        NULL);

    if (ptyOutM == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        fail=true;
        snprintf(errorText,256,"Could not open ptyM: %s.",ptyName);
        CloseHandle(ptyInS);
        CloseHandle(ptyInM);
        return false;
    }

    ptyOutS = CreateFile (
        (LPCSTR) ptyName,
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        &sAtr,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
        NULL);

    if (ptyOutS == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        fail=true;
        snprintf(errorText,256,"Could not open ptyS: %s.",ptyName);
        CloseHandle(ptyOutM);
        CloseHandle(ptyInS);
        CloseHandle(ptyInM);
        return false;
    }

    ptyOpen = true;


    ZeroMemory (&prInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    ZeroMemory (&stInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    stInfo.cb = sizeof(stInfo); 
    stInfo.hStdError = ptyOutS;
    stInfo.hStdOutput = ptyOutS;
    stInfo.hStdInput = ptyInS;
    stInfo.dwXCountChars = (DWORD)width;
    stInfo.dwYCountChars = (DWORD)((mode==modeHR)?heightHR:heightLR);
    stInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    stInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USECOUNTCHARS |  STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;

    if (!CreateProcess (
        applName,
        cmdLine,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        TRUE,
        // CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
        DETACHED_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP,
        NULL, //ENV!!
        NULL, //CWD!!
        &stInfo,
        &prInfo
    )) {
        fail = true;
        snprintf(errorText,256,"Could not CreateProcess.");
        CloseHandle(ptyOutS);
        CloseHandle(ptyOutM);
        CloseHandle(ptyInS);
        CloseHandle(ptyInM);
        ptyOpen = false;
        return false;
    }

    CloseHandle(ptyOutS);
    CloseHandle(ptyInS);
    CloseHandle(prInfo.hThread);
    ptyIn = ptyInM;
    ptyOut = ptyOutM;
    pidHandle = prInfo.hProcess;
    pid = prInfo.dwProcessId;
    commandRunning = true;

    return true;
#else
    int ptyM, ptyS;
    int i;
    struct termios termp;
    int flags;

    if (commandRunning)
        return false;

    fail=false;

    i=openpty(&ptyM,&ptyS,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    if (i<0) {
        fail = true;
        snprintf(errorText,256,"Could not open pty.");
        return false;
    }
    i=tcgetattr(ptyM, &termp);
    // cfmakeraw(&termp);
    i|=tcsetattr(ptyM, TCSANOW, &termp);
    flags=fcntl(ptyM, F_GETFL);
    flags|=O_NONBLOCK;
    i|=fcntl(ptyM, F_SETFL, flags);
    if (i<0) {
        fail = true;
        snprintf(errorText,256,"Could not modify pty mode");
        close(ptyM);
        close(ptyS);
        return false;
    }
    ptyOpen = true;

    switch (pid=fork()) {
    case -1:
        fail = true;
        snprintf(errorText,256,"Could not fork");
        close(ptyM);
        close(ptyS);
        ptyOpen = false;
        // printf("LOL FAIL FORK\n");
        return false;
        break;
    case 0:
        setsid();
        dup2(ptyS, STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(ptyS, STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(ptyS, STDERR_FILENO);
        if (ioctl(ptyS, TIOCSCTTY, NULL) < 0)
            exit(1);
        close(ptyM);
        close(ptyS);
        clearenv();
        // printf("I AM FORK\n");
        execl("./load","./load","test",NULL);
        printf("LOL FAIL EXEC");
        exit(1);
        break;
    default:
        commandRunning = true;
        close(ptyS);
        pty=ptyM;
        // printf("SUCCESS FORK\n");
        break;
    }
    return true;
#endif
}
```

As you can see it's the same function done twice, once for Windows and once for GNU/Linux, selected by an #ifdef.

And this is the code which is doing the communication:

```
bool LemlTerm::perform() {
    bool nextline;
    unsigned short canRead1, canRead2, canWrite1, canWrite2;
#ifdef LEML_WIN32
    DWORD n;
#else
    ssize_t n;
#endif

    fail = false;

    ++blinkCount;
    if(ringCount)
        --ringCount;

    if (commandRunning) {
#ifdef LEML_WIN32
        if (WaitForSingleObject(pidHandle,0) != WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
            CloseHandle(pidHandle);
            commandRunning = false;
        }
#else
        if (waitpid (pid, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0 )
            commandRunning = false;
#endif
    }
    //TODO: how and when to close pty!!

    canWrite1 = (outRd - outWr - 1)&0xff;
    if(canWrite1 > (256-outWr)) {
        canWrite2 = canWrite1 + outWr - 256;
        canWrite1 -= canWrite2;
    } else {
        canWrite2 = 0;
    }

    printf("rd:%hu wr:%hu cw:%hu+%hu=%hu\n",outRd, outWr, canWrite1, canWrite2, canWrite1+canWrite2);

    if (canWrite1) {
#ifdef LEML_WIN32
        ReadFile(ptyOut, outputBuffer+outWr, (DWORD)canWrite1, &n, NULL);
#else       
        n=read(pty, outputBuffer+outWr, (size_t)canWrite1);
#endif
        printf("%hu\n",(unsigned short*)n);
        if (n>0) {
            outWr += n;
            outWr &= 0xff;
            if ((n==canWrite1) && canWrite2) {
#ifdef LEML_WIN32
                ReadFile(ptyOut, outputBuffer+outWr, (DWORD)canWrite2, &n, NULL);
#else       
                n=read(pty, outputBuffer+outWr, (size_t)canWrite2);
#endif
                printf("%hu\n",(unsigned short*)n);
                if (n>0) {
                    outWr += n;
                    outWr &= 0xff;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (; outWr!=outRd; outRd=(outRd+1)&0xff) {
        screenChanged = true;
        nextline=false;

        switch (outputBuffer[outRd]) {
        case 7: //bell
            ringCount += 0x10;
            break;
        case 8: //backspace
            outputBuffer[outRd]=' ';
            if (cursorX>0) {
                --cursorX;
            } else if (cursorY>0) {
                --cursorY;
                cursorX = width;
            }
            textBuffer[(bufferY+cursorY)%heightHR][cursorX] = ' ';
            break;
        case 9: //tab
            cursorX &= ~0x7;
            cursorX += 8;
            if(cursorX >= width) {
                cursorX = 0;
                nextline = true;
            }
            break;
        case 10: //newline
            cursorX = 0;
        case 11: //vt
        case 12: //ff
            nextline = true;
            break;
        case 13: //cr
            cursorX = 0;
            break;
        default:
            textBuffer[(bufferY+cursorY)%heightHR][cursorX] = outputBuffer[outRd];
            ++cursorX;
            if(cursorX >= width) {
                cursorX = 0;
                nextline = true;
            }
        }

        if (nextline) {
            // cursorX = 0;
            if (cursorY < ((mode==modeHR)?heightHR:heightLR) - 1) {
                ++cursorY;
            } else {
                ++bufferY;
                bufferY %= heightHR;
            }
            // memset(textBuffer[(bufferY+cursorY)%heightHR],(bufferY+cursorY)%heightHR,width);
            memset(textBuffer[(bufferY+cursorY)%heightHR],' ',width);

            //optional! for simulate scrolling delay...
            outRd=(outRd+1)&0xff;
            break; 
        }
        // //SUPER SLOW
        // outRd=(outRd+1)&0xff;
        // break; 
    }

    canRead1 = (inWr-inRd)&0x1f;
    if(canRead1 > (32-inRd)) {
        canRead2 = canRead1 + inRd - 32;
        canRead1 -= canRead2;
    } else {
        canRead2 = 0;
    }


    if (canRead1) {
        printf("rd:%hu wr:%hu cr:%hu+%hu=%hu\n",inRd, inWr, canRead1, canRead2, canRead1+canRead2);
#ifdef LEML_WIN32
        WriteFile(ptyIn, inputBuffer+inRd, (DWORD)canRead1, &n, NULL);
#else       
        n=write(pty, inputBuffer+inRd, (size_t)canRead1);
#endif
        printf("%hu\n",(unsigned short*)n);
        if (n>0) {
            inRd += n;
            inRd &= 0x1f;
            if ((n==canRead1) && canRead2) {
#ifdef LEML_WIN32
                WriteFile(ptyIn, inputBuffer+inRd, (DWORD)canRead2, &n, NULL);
#else
                n=write(pty, inputBuffer+inRd, (size_t)canRead2);
#endif
                printf("%hu\n",(unsigned short*)n);
                if (n>0) {
                    inRd += n;
                    inRd &= 0x1f;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return updateScreen();
}
```

It's a function which is called once per iteration of main loop (once for frame)
If checks if guest program is still running,
reads from programs output and writes it to a circular output buffer,
goes through the circular output buffer and puts the content info a screen buffer,
reads from a circular input buffer (data get in there when handling keyboard) and writes it to the program's input,
calls a screen update.
And while doing all this prints some debug info.

I don't know what I am doing wrong which results with blocking (only on Wine) and unwanted buffering (on Windows).

**My question is, what else do I have to do to achieve communication through pipes without blocking and without buffering forever on Windows?**

I am aware that ConPTY exists (the windows' new pseudoterminal equivalent). But it's a new feature available since Windows 10 1809.
The only reason that I'm considering Windows at all is that a lot of people use Windows only and I would like them to be able to use the programs I make. Using this new feature will exclude all those who use older systems, so a lot of people (including me, as I also don't have this new Windows 10).

Also I'm aware that pipes don't have all the features of a pseudoterminals like line-editing, sending signals to programs, control sequences, etc. and if I need any of thes features I would have to do them by myself, but other than the line-editing (which I can do) I should not probably not need them.

I included only the code which is related to the inter-process communication. But if needed I can provide the whole demo.
The demo is written in C++, however this problem is equally relevant to C.

Comment: You're telling the OS not to buffer the file, but the C++ app can (and frequently does) buffer output internally before writing to the OS.  If you're using standard output with `cout` or something similar, you can use `endl` (which includes a flush), or call `flush()` when you're done generating output and are ready to pass it along.

Comment: "The demo is written in C++, however this problem is equally relevant to C". **The problem** may be relevant to both (heck it may even be relevant to Java, python etc). However, **the solution** could be different depending on the language. That's why Stack Overflow questions are encouraged to use only a single language tag.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, thank you for the idea of flushing in the guest app. The guest app is written in C so I added fflush() but this does not change anything. Also, I guess if that was the source of the problem then it would probably also observed when running it directly in the windows console instead of my terminal demo, but on the windows console it runs like expected.